# Drawing uneven circle using JavaFX

Tags: javafx, java-8

I'm looking for some ideas how to draw uneven circle using JavaFX. I need something like this:
[image]

The only idea I have is to use many Cubic Curves with staring and ending points on circle's border. Is there any simpler way? Some effect I can add to an existing circle?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://www.guigarage.com/2014/11/hand-drawing-effect-javafx/